# Control compilation order in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, compilation, collation, rcpp

In R, using Rcpp to access C++ code, without putting all of the C++ code on a single file, how can I control the order which the files are used when compilation takes place.

Lets say I have 2 methods, `methodPrimary` and `methodSecondary`, I want to put each method on separate files `methodPrimary.cpp` and `methodSecondary.cpp`, but let say function `methodPrimary` uses function `methodSecondary`, as below:

**methodSecodary.cpp**

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int methodSecondary(int i){
  return(i);
}
```

**methodPrimary.cpp**

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int methodPrimary(int i){
  return 2*methodSecondary(i);
}
```

I get an error thrown, saying `methodSecondary` not declared in this scope, which is understandable, since in each of the two files, there is no reference to the other. respectively.

My initial presumption was that the Rcpp compiler would handle all of this along with package construction and use of the `Collate` field, seemingly not the case.

So my question is, what is the correct process to have all the files compiled/processed/declared in the correct order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compilation order does not matter.  But each function must be declared before the compiler will accept it.

Create a header file which declares all of your functions, and include it into each `C` source file.

`methods.h`:

```
extern int methodPrimary(int);
extern int methodSecondary(int);
```

In each `C` source file, prior to using the functions:

```
#include "methods.h"
```

You can use multiple header files, so that `methodSecondary.h` declares just that function.

Comment: Yeah that works, the `#include "methods.h"` needs to use "" not <>.

Comment: `<>` is for system header files.